# separating from jquery removeClass method

Tags: jquery, removeclass

Live : http://jsbin.com/ibolaf/2/

I'am learning jquery from the jq source, I try to separating some method out from the big lib.I think it's right,but it do not!

This removeClass method I'am separate form jq has remove the className,but rewrite an 'undefined' instead.I think the problem is occur in the trim function.Also,the trim method is form the jquery.

```
removeClass(this,test);
```

Before:

```
<ul class="test demo" id="ul">
```

After:

```
<ul class="undefined" id="ul">
```

I think it should be

```
<ul class="demo" id="ul">
```

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: The className 'test' removed but returns undefined in UL's class,you don't see it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "separate method from jquery" and expect things to work.
That method you are trying to separate has **dependencies**.
First one being **jQuery object**.

Jquery isn't just a stack of separately reusable functions.

It doesn't work that way.

Comment: You cannot improve it outside of jquery.
You have to use whole jquery.

Comment: You mean I should write anther one that has no dependencies?

Comment: I just wanna write a better removeClass function,but I don't want to use jquery.

Comment: You cannot take a function from jquery and use it separately, even improved.
It is a bad idea.

You can write your own function, but you need to know good javascript.